# Cannot assign "...'": "TestData.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

Very new to the Django Rest Framework, so would appreciate some help with this one. I get the error in the title when I try and do a POST request in Postman with an appropriate auth token.

I've made a table that I want to send a POST request to, but having issues with getting a user FK to be accepted as one of the columns. Plz see model/serializer/view below:

**Model**

```
class TestData (models.Model):
TestSDG = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=2, default=0)
user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", related_name="testdata", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer**

```
class TestDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = TestData
    fields = ('id', 'TestSDG')
```

**View**

```
@csrf_exempt
def testDataApi(request, id=0):
if request.method == 'GET':
    testdata = TestData.objects.all()
    testdata_serializer = TestDataSerializer(testdata,many=True)
    return JsonResponse(testdata_serializer.data,safe=False)
elif request.method == 'POST':
    testdata_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
    testdata_serializer=TestDataSerializer(data=testdata_data)
    if testdata_serializer.is_valid():
        testdata_serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return JsonResponse("Added Successfully", safe=False)
```

The POST request works fine if I don't use the user as a foreign key, and I change `testdata_serializer.save(user=request.user)` back to `testdata_serializer.save()`, but I want the table to require a user's id.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `ModelViewset` in your views.py file - then you can override the `update` method on your serializer:

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class TestDataViewSet(ModelViewSet):
 
    queryset = TestData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestDataSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```py
class TestDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # get user id from validated data:
        user_id = validated_data.pop('user_id')

        # get user:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        # set user on instance:
        instance.user = user
        instance.save()

        # continue with update method:
        super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: The way you've outlined seems a bit different to how I've done things (that being said I was just following a basic video that didn't cover FK connections between tables so maybe I was doing it wrong). 

I don't quite understand what's happening in the update method. I get that it's getting the user_id and saving it to the user instance, but I am unsure how to access it after that point. 

I've attempted to access it in testDataApi and/or in an equivalent update method in views.py, but I'm getting integrity issues because the user_id is still null.

Comment: The  `ModelViewSet` is a class that contains predefined get, list, post, etc. methods so that you don't need to write them yourself. It pairs nicely with the `ModelSerializer`, however one limitation is that the serializer does a poor job of handling nested objects, hence we still need to override the update method to do things like getting or creating a nested object.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, got it working using your method. Made some GET/POST methods in the view under the ModelViewSet that reference the user request and that works no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you are using an auth token. Try verifying in your view `testDataApi` if `request.user` was correctly set with an `auth.User` object. Try logging it with something like below to make sure that it is correctly set to the user for the provided token:

```
@csrf_exempt
def testDataApi(request, id=0):
    print(type(request.user), request.user)  # Should display the user for the provided token.
    ...
```

If it isn't set, then you have to configure how it would correctly map an `auth.User` object from a provided token. You might want to look at the following:

- [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) - Sets the `request.user` object.
- [AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) - Custom authentication of a token and then return the associated `auth.User` object
- [DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) - Only if using `djangorestframework`. Sets the `request.user` object.

  - [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), [JSONWebTokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication), etc. - Only if using `djangorestframework`. Some implementations that authenticates tokens. Perhaps they weren't configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that - yeah, it's only finding an anonymous user so the auth.user object probably isn't being mapped. I'll take a look through those resources.